# How to freeze the first position of the recyclerview and other position to be scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling, android-listadapter

How to freeze the recyclerview first position, so that first position act as toolbar. And other position to be scrollable.[image]

Consider above image as example. I am using multiple view type in Recyclerview. I need to fix or freeze the 0th position permanently at the top and other position to scroll as normal Recyclerview.

**Note:**
Recyclerview must use in this case, no other view above the Recyclerview is used to solve the problem

Comment: I think there's no direct way to do this with a standard RecyclerView because the RecyclerView was not designed to have fixed positions. What you can try is to have a text view on top of your recycler view that says "Playlist".